# How do I make a <div> stay on the bottom of the screen unless there is overflow?

Tags: html, css

I want my website to have a  that is used as a footer, but I want it to stay at the bottom of the page, but when I add content to the website, I want the  to go down with the overflow. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, so please share your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or update your question with other effort you made.

Comment: To be fair, it's hard to know the exact words to describe the behavior. Hopefully someone else with this set of keywords will now know that the term to look for is "sticky"

Answer (score 3):

The term you're looking for is sticky footer or fixed footer and can be accomplished in a few ways see [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/). Have a look on google and try it out, then if you're still struggling post what you've tried.

EDIT: Fair enough.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    Footer 
</footer>
```

Style using flex:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; 
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto; 
  padding: 20px;
}
.footer {  
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
}
```